# Two separate instances of SQL Server running a different explain plan

Tags: sql-server

Here's one I need help from the SQL administrators out there.  I have two separate SQL Server instances on Amazon EC2.  One is our staging environment, and the other is our production environment, but they are configured exactly the same way (spawned from the same image).

We had a database that we copied from staging to our production environment last week.  The way we copy a db to production is we take a backup of it on our staging site, and restore the backup in production.  Anyways, we found that in production, one particular complex query was timing out after an hour, but that exact query in our staging environment completed in 10 minutes.

The explain plan on both were almost the same, except in one server it was doing a PK scan on a large table (8M rows), and on the other table it was doing an index seek.  We're assuming this was the difference.  So one server was doing a lot of disk IO, and the other was not.

So my question is, what are the reasons that one installation of SQL server would decide to use an index, while another one ignores it--assuming same versions of SQL server, and same data set?  Even better, what are the best ways to find out why SQL is ignoring an index?

Comment: You may get a better response to this sort of question over at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was our mistake.

After much digging investigation, we found that one of our devs had added a couple additional indexes to the production db after the transfer.  This was a case where the additional indexes actually caused the query optimizer to pick a less efficient route in the production environment.

Removing those additional indexes appeared to have addressed the performance issue for the particular query, and both explain plans are now the same.

Answer (score 3):

`SQL Server` uses statistics to determine the query execution plan.

Normally, they should be the same on the same datasets, but there is a chance of outdated statistics on one of the machines.

Use `sp_updatestats` to update statistics on both machines.

Also, I'm not familiar with `Amazon EC2`, but there may be a chance that the machines running the two instances have different number of `CPU` installed (or made available for use by `SQL Server`). This is also taken into account by the optimizer.

Comment: Regarding statistics, they should be the same.  We ran sp_updatestats on the staging server before we made a backup and restored it in the production server.  We could try running sp_updatestats on both again later on...

Answer (score 2):

[Parameter Sniffing?](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3841271/T-SQL-Best-Practices--Parameter-Sniffing.htm)

An SP will use the query plan that was deemed most appropriate based on the parameters passed to it when it was executed (and so compiled) for the first time.

Restoring a database wipes the plan cache; if the SP on the copy of the database was run with parameters that favored an index seek, then that's what will subsequently be used.

You can check this by `sp_recompile`'ing both and running them again with identical parameters.

Comment: Hmm.. might be on to something here.  I'll give this a shot later to see if this is the cause.

Comment: Just tried doing sp_recompile.  Unfortunately that did not change the behavior, so I'm not so sure what is going on again.

Comment: Is the seek|scan the only difference in the plans? does one mention a parallelism step and the other not?